Vue-advanced-cropper custom slider that zooms in and out
I am working on a custom zoom slider for the 'vue-advanced-cropper' tool, which allows users to crop images. The slider currently zooms in perfectly but does not allow users to zoom out. it needs to be able to zoom both in and out to adjust images accurately. I need to fix the issue that prevents zooming out, allowing users to have full control over their images.
          <Cropper
                ref="$cropper"
                :src="logo.src"
                :default-position="{ top: 0, left: 0 }"
                :default-size="
                  ({ imageSize }) => ({
                    width: imageSize.width,
                    height: imageSize.height,
                  })
                "
                class="cropper"
                backgroundClass="cropper-background"
                :image="image" 
                auto-zoom
                @change="cropperOnChange"
              />
            </div>
            <ZoomSlider @zoom-changed="handleZoomChange" />

script
export default {
components: {
  ZoomSlider
},
data() {
  return {
    image: null, 
  }
},
methods: {
  handleZoomChange(newZoomLevel) {
  this.zoomLevel = newZoomLevel;
  
  // Ensure that zoom level is within valid bounds, e.g., 0.1 to 3.0
  const minZoomLevel = 0.1;
  const maxZoomLevel = 5.0;
  this.zoomLevel = Math.min((minZoomLevel, this.zoomLevel), Math.max(maxZoomLevel, this.zoomLevel));
  
  // Apply the zoom level to the cropper
  this.$refs.$cropper.zoom(this.zoomLevel);
},
}
}

Slider Component
    <template>
    <div>
      <input type="range" :max="maxZoom" :min="minZoom" v-model="zoomLevel" />
      <span>{{ zoomLevel }}</span>
    </div>
  </template>
  
  <script>
  export default {
    props: {
      maxZoom: {
        type: Number,
        default: 5
      },
      minZoom: {
        type: Number,
        default: 0  
      }
    },
    data() {
      return {
        zoomLevel: 0
      }
    },
    watch: {
      zoomLevel(newZoom) {
        this.$emit('zoom-changed', newZoom)
      }
    }
  }
  </script>

Thanks for the help! let me know if i did not provide enough info.

currently working on a slider and it's quite tricky, not so good right now.
but it's not a zoom as a level, has i understood it's a relatif zoom.
i dit something like that in my project
watch(zoom, (value, previous) => {
    if (value < previous) {
        console.log('zoom out');

        cropper.value?.zoom(0.8);
    }
    else {
        console.log('zoom in');
        cropper.value?.zoom(1.2);
    }
});

is number is bigger than before it zoom inside from is current zoom 1.2, and if smaller zoom out from .8
EDIT
check that it's should fit your need
https://advanced-cropper.github.io/vue-advanced-cropper/guides/showcase.html#twitter

i think i've to do some math to get some fancy zoom in zoom out because right now its act  step by step
